# CS0103 - The name 'GetListFromCVS' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, solid-principles, csvhelper

Pretty new to C# and object-oriented programming in general. I'm currently recieving this error when trying to call GetListFromCSV method that resides in another ".cs" file but resides in the same namespace. I'm not sure why I'm not able to call this method?

I originally had the code in GetListFromCSV method in main but wanted to put it in it's own class file to practice the SOLID principles. Maybe it doesn't make sense in this case?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Main:

```
using MathNet.Numerics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SimPump_Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get CSV file location
            string dirCSVLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string fileCSVLocation = dirCSVLocation + @"\PumpCurveCSVFiles\pumpcurve.csv";

            // Read CSV contents into variable "records"
            //CSVToList CSVIsntance = new CSVToList();
            List<PumpCurveCSVInput> records = GetListFromCVS(fileCSVLocation);

            //float pumpFlowOutput;
            double[] pumpFlow = new double[records.Count];
            double[] pumpHead = new double[records.Count];

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                //if (record.pumpHead == 50)
                //{
                //    pumpFlowOutput = record.pumpFlow;
                //}

                pumpFlow[i] = record.pumpFlow;
                pumpHead[i] = record.pumpHead;

                i++;
            }

            // Determine pump curve
            Polynomial.Fit(pumpFlow, pumpHead, 3);


        }
    }
}
```

GetListFromCSV Method:

```
using CsvHelper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace SimPump_Demo
{
    public class CSVToList
    {
        public static List<PumpCurveCSVInput> GetListFromCVS(string fileCSV)
        {
            List<PumpCurveCSVInput> records;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileCSV))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                records = csv.GetRecords<PumpCurveCSVInput>().ToList();
            }

            return records;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetListFromCVS()` is a member of the type `CSVToList` and you are trying to call it from `Main()` which is a member of type `Program`.  So you need to do `CSVToList.GetListFromCVS(fileCSVLocation);`

Comment: Docs: [Static classes and static class members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `GetListFromCVS` is a static method, it still belongs to the `CSVToList` class. Therefore you must call it like this:

```cs
List<PumpCurveCSVInput> records = CSVToList.GetListFromCVS(fileCSVLocation);
```

Just use the name of the class without creating an instance.

If you make your method non-static

```cs
public class CSVToList
{
    public List<PumpCurveCSVInput> GetListFromCVS(string fileCSV)
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

In that case you should create an instance of the `CSVToList` class before being able to use this method

```cs
var csvHelper = new CSVToList();
List<PumpCurveCSVInput> records = csvHelper.GetListFromCVS(fileCSVLocation);
```

Comment: Wow, I forgot I had to include the class name there... Thanks! I appreciate the additional context around non-static method calling as well! I have not used non-static methods before (and honestly not sure what it even means currently) but I know it will be useful later on. Thanks again!

Comment: Classes can have `properties` and `fields` of any types to hold values representing the state of your object. When you create an instance of a class you end up with a variable (in my exemple `csvHelper`) which we call an `object` (hence the term `OOP`). Non-static methods are called using your object so they can access the fields and properties of your object. Static methods on the opposite aren't executed on an object but directly using your class name so they can't access any property or field you declared in your class. You'll learn how to use one or the other as you progress